# Load image, resize, save as resized image?

Tags: android

I'm now developing a simple android app that has to load an image using image picker, show in imageviewer  and resize the image and thin save it as a new resized image (NOT SHOW ON GALLERY).

Please help me, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Are `image picker` and `imageviewer` specific tools, or are they tools you have to create? What have you tried? [Here](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/157) is a resource to help you find external tools, but you need to provide some code and an issue if we are to help you.

Comment: Thanks man! i will try them.